# For OAuth2, can one user send OAuth login url to another user, trying to access the other user's data?

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth

If I have a website A, and needs to use Website B's OAuth provided by their authorization server. When User 1 uses website A, it generates a OAuth login url. Meanwhile, user 2 attempts to the same. Is it possible for user 1 to send the OAuth login URL generated for him/her to user 2? Then user 2 enters his/her credential of website B. After this workflow, website A will use user 2's refresh token/access on website B to fetch data, but the data will be exposed to user 1 on website A. I know this is an edge case, but it is completely possible. And according to OAuth2 specification https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/redirect-uris/redirect-uri-validation/, only redirect URL is validated via allowlisting. But it doesn't say anything about validating the callback request in the 3rd party website.

Comment: After User2 authenticates, why should the user1 get an AccessToken?

Comment: Because User 1 as the attacker send OAuth login url generated for user 1 to user 2, and user 2 links his/her account of website B

Comment: To clarify, we are talking about the authorization-code flow, right? Which has, upon others, the redirect_uri parameter, which is used to redirect the UserAgent of User2 to the redirect_uri, after User2 has successfully authenticated. The call to the authorization endpoint (I am guessing thats what you meant with login url) normally does not contain any user specific parameters. Am I getting your question wrong?

Comment: Right. I'm talking about the OAuth callback redirect request from user 2's browser to  Website A's endpoint. In the url parameters of the redirect request, there will grant code (returned by website B's auth server) of user 2, and state token (generated by website A) of user 1. How can website A discover that there is a mismatch?